# Undefined Index in a jquery AJAX send and receive data request

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

test.php

```
$aaa = $_POST['aaa'];

echo $aaa;
```

Javascript Code

```
$.ajax({

url: 'ajax/test.php', 
data: { aaa: 'names_' },
success: function(data) {
alert("Data Loaded: " + data); 
            }
      });
```

The alert response is:

```
NOTICE: Undefined Index: aaa
```

What might cause this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add to the ajax object the type attribute:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/test.php', 
  type:'post',
  data: { aaa: 'names_' },
  success: function(data) {
    alert("Data Loaded: " + data); 
  }
});
```

Comment: @PedroEsperança If it's not obvious, the default value for `type` is "get".

Comment: No problem, I'm glad to help and have fun at the same time :)

Answer (score 1):

You should claim the submit method

```
$.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  ...
});
```

Comment: post needs to be in quotes (like 'post' or 'POST'), otherwise it will not work

Answer (score -1):

data: {'aaa':'names_'} 
I think will be better

Comment: All specifying `data` does is make a shorthand for the key/value pairs for the GET or POST request and will be converted to strings anyways. So since this is a valid Javascript object, that has no effect.